# Why is my root view controller getting pushed along with intended view when using navigationController.pushViewController()?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController that is inside a navigation controller. When I push another view controller to the navigation stack it is pushed on top of a copy of the root view controller. The copy can be seen in the background and can be interacted with and tapped. The views are made programmatically without a storyboard or xibs.

I have tried to test with a UIButton and a nav item button and the same thing happens. I cannot find out why it is sending both view controllers.

this is my main view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let countries = ["US", "UK", ...] //an array of strings
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        setupUI()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.tableView.register(FlagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FlagCell.identifier)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FlagCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! FlagCell
        let country = countries[indexPath.row]
        let image = UIImage(named: country)
        cell.flagImageView.image = image
        cell.countryNameLabel.text = country
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = FlagViewController()
        let image = UIImage(named: countries[indexPath.row])
        vc.flagView.image = image
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is my detail view controller

```
import UIKit

class FlagViewController: ViewController {

    let flagView: UIImageView = {
        let flagView = UIImageView()
        return flagView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UI Setup
    private func setupUI() {
        self.view.addSubview(flagView)
        flagView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            flagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            flagView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            flagView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            flagView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            
            flagView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            flagView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: While likely to be unrelated, is there a reason your `ViewController` class extends `UIViewController` with your own added table view instead of extending `UITableViewController`?

Comment: You wrote `class FlagViewController: ViewController`, but shouldn't that be `class FlagViewController: UIViewController`?

Comment: @Sweeper That was the problem, the detail view controller was conforming to "ViewController" (the class name for my main view controller). After changing to "UIViewController" it is working as intended.

Comment: @HangarRash I have it extending because I was under the impression it may be better practice or more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by replacing

```
class FlagViewController: ViewController {...}
```

with the below code, stopping my detail view controller from conforming to my main view controller class.

```
class FlagViewController: UIViewController {...}
```